# something like pattern matching list in prolog

Tags: prolog

`[A,B,C|_] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
A = 1
B = 2
C = 3.`
I expected this result.   However, when I have:

```
L = [A,B,C,D]
```

how to do:

```
L = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]  
A = 1
B = 2
C = 3
D = 4
```

?

The problem is that I don't know how long is `L`. Only thing that I know:  `L` is shorter than rightside list and `L` contains only variables.

Comment: Looks like you're "overloading" what you mean by `L` here. So it's making the question "how to do" a little unclear (you aren't showing a complete query). I assume you have a list of variables, `L`, and then another list you want to unify with the front of? `M = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], L = [A,B,C,D], append(L, _, M).` would yield the results for `A` through `D`. `L` could be a list of variables of any length. Of course if the length of `L` exceeds the length of `M`, it fails as expected.

Comment: It would be `L=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7], L=[A,B,C,D|_]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We just "insert the free variable" at the variables list's tail, `append(Vars, _, ExtendedList)`, and then pattern match, `ExtendedList = Data`. Contracting, we get:

```
match_vars(Vars, Data):-
    append(Vars, _, Data).
```

Testing:

```
2 ?- match_vars([A,B],[1,2,3,4,5]).
A = 1,
B = 2.

3 ?- match_vars([A,B,C,D],[1,2,3,4,5]).
A = 1,
B = 2,
C = 3,
D = 4.

4 ?-
```

*(using [`append/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=append/3) was already mentioned [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37326128/something-like-pattern-matching-list-in-prolog#comment62171746_37326128)).*